# ¿Cómo se crean "alias" en Apache Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, web.config, configuración

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web que permite a los usuarios subir archivos. Estos archivos adjuntos se almacenan en una unidad diferente a la de la aplicación web *G:/Adjuntos*. 
¿Cómo puedo crear un alias (equivalente a los alias del servidor Apache HTTP) para que los usuarios puedan descargar estos archivos adjuntos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución con el siguiente código en el archivo server.xml en la ruta 
*conf*

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
    xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

 <Context path="/attachments"
             docBase="g:\contenedores"
             reloadable="true"
             crossContext="true" />
```